# C# Selenium Closing a randomly appearing light box

Tags: c#, selenium

I am trying to close a light box which only pops up occasionally/randomly.  I realize I can use explicit waits to wait for the light box's close button to be visible, however, it will wastefully bottleneck my throughput on all the page loads that do not contain the light box.

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(WaitTimeout));
wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(LightBoxCloseButtonSelector));
```

Is there even a solution to this problem?  Maybe some FluentWait magic?  Perhaps JavascriptExecutor?

Comment: You can always check if it exists first on DOM (if not, chances are it will not suddenly appear), and then wait for it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by executing the following Javascript with JavaScriptExecutor on each page load:

```
var divs=document.getElementsByClassName('CLASS_NAME_OF_OVERLAY_CONTAINER');for(var i=0;i<divs.length;i++){divs[i].style.display='none'}
```